# Refresh page while element is not presented with cucumber-nightwatch (selenium web driver)

Tags: cucumber, nightwatch.js

I need to refresh page while element is not presented
i'm trying something like this, but it doesn't help

```
    When(/^"([^"]*)" task status changed$/, taskName => {
    let needRefresh = true;

    do {
        client.url(`${client.globals.env.url}${client.globals.env.index}/messaging/messages`)
            .pause(10000)
            .getTagName(`//div[contains(@class, "task-checkbox")]//*[contains(text(), "${taskName}")]`, res => {
               client.equal(res.value, 'div')
        }).pause(20000);

    } while (!needRefresh)

});
```

how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use complex asynchronous operations I suggest to use the new `async` functions. If your NodeJs version does not support it natively I suggest to use Babel. There is an example for that in the `nightwatch-cucumber` [example folder](https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber/tree/master/examples/babel-example). To be able to refresh the page until some condition you can use the following example.

```
When(/^"([^"]*)" task status changed$/, async (taskName) => {
  let needRefresh = true;

  do {
    await client.refresh();
    await client.pause(10000);

    needRefresh = await client.getTagName(...
  } while (!needRefresh)
});
```